# VersionOne Continuum Task error with WinRM/Powershell command

Tags: versionone, continuum

We currently have an issue where we are deploying a project from the package in continuum. My task converts all the package details into a json object and it sends the object through WinRM to the PowerShell script. This is working for all our products, but we have 1 package that currently says that it is too large to send.

The error message is simply `The request is too long`

I suspect perhaps there are more error details that the Task does not show me.  I do not have easy access to the server to research this from the receiving end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some limitations you'll face when doing WinRM and Powershell. Looks like you are hitting the command line length limit.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation

as per this documentation, one of the suggested work around is to pass the parameters in a file.

IIRC there is an 8000+ character limit for a command over winRM, and a 2000 character limit per parameter into the powershell script.  This is most likely the issue.  Not knowing the exact details of your payload, I'd suggest trying to thin down what you're sending.  Does your powershell script really need the entire package payload? It's pretty verbose.

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct, I did not need all the package details.  I cut the payload down to just what I do need and it's significantly smaller, and is now working just fine.  Thanks!